# Tricky exercise about proving two subspaces gives rise to a direct sum of the whole vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\phi:V \to V$ be a linear operator of a finite vector space over the field $K$ such as $\phi^{2}=1_{V}$. Prove the subsets $V_{1}:=\lbrace v \in V \: | \: \phi(v)=v \rbrace$ and $V_{-1}:=\lbrace v \in V \: | \: \phi(v)=-v \rbrace$ are linear subspaces of $V$ and  also $V=V_{1} \oplus V_{-1}$.  It was straight-forward to prove that $V_{1},V_{-1}$ are linear subspaces of $V$, the problem arises proving that $V=V_{1} \oplus V_{-1}$.

Lets prove first that $V_{1} \cap V_{-1}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, so lets suppose there is a $v \in V_{1} \cap V_{-1}$ so $\phi(v)=v$ and $\phi(v)=-v$, this means $v=\phi(v)=-v$ so....this implies $v=0$??

Then by taking a $v \in V$ I want to find vectors $v_{1} \in V_{1}$ and $v_{2} \in V_{-1}$ such $v=v_{1}+v_{2}$. So my idea is to show that every $v\in V$ lies in $V_{1}$ or $V_{-1}$ so without lost of generality if $v\in V_{1}$ then $v=v_{1}+0$.  So far I have not seen when the hypothesis of $\phi^{2}=1_{V}$ is used so I guess my attempts are not in the right way :/ . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: Since $\phi^{2}=1_{V}$, if $\phi(v)=0$, then $v=1_{V}(v) = \phi^{2}(v)= \phi(0)=0$.

Comment: You are saying the Hint is the fact $phi$ is an injective linear operator? @Ramiro

Comment: The condition $\phi^{2}=1_{V}$ implies that $\phi$ is a bijective linear operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every $v\in V$ is in one of $V_1$ or $V_{-1}.$ Consider for example $V = \Bbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ with $\phi(z) = \overline{z}.$ Then you can check that $V_1 = \{a + 0i\mid a\in\Bbb{R}\}$ and $V_{-1} = \{0 + bi\mid b\in\Bbb{R}\}.$ As such, a complex number like $1 + i$ is not in either of $V_1$ or $V_{-1}.$ However, it can certainly be written as a sum of vectors in $V_1$ and $V_{-1}$: $1\in V_1$ and $i\in V_{-1}$.

You must start with an arbitrary $v\in V$ and show that it can be written as $v = v_1 + v_{-1},$ where $v_i\in V_i$ ($i = \pm1$). **Hint:** consider the vectors $v - \phi(v)$ and $v + \phi(v).$ What can you say about these?

**Final Remark:** You need to assume that $\operatorname{char}K\neq 2$ for this result to be true. If $\operatorname{char}K = 2,$ then $V_1 = V_{-1},$ and we need not have $V = V_1 = V_{-1}.$ As an example, let $K$ be any field of characteristic $2,$ let $V = K^2,$ and let $\phi(a,b) = (b,a).$ Then $V_1 = \{(a,b)\in V\mid a = b\},$ but this is not the whole space ($\dim V_1 = 1$ while $\dim V = 2$).

Comment: Well, I got that $v-\phi(v)$ belongs to $V_{-1}$ and $v+\phi(v)$ belongs to $V_{1}$ but still wondering how I write $v$ as a sum of these two :/ @Stahl

Comment: @Cos Well, $v$ isn't a sum of those two. You'll need to tweak them. What do you get when you add them? How can you fix this so that you can "make $v$ out of them?"

Comment: I got $2v$ by suming these two I just need to get rid of one $v$ still struggling by fixing this problem maybe I need to think in other way of prove this as I think im not getting the idea of the hint you propose me. Also the hint I got first at my answer says to me $\phi$ is also bijective but this confuse me @Stahl

Comment: @Cos If $2v = w,$ then $v = w/2.$ I wouldn't worry about using bijectivity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just wondering if assuming $charK \neq 2$ as you said my prove of $V_{1} \cap V_{-1}= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is right? I got that $2v=0$ implying $v=0$ right? Also wondering how I can develope more my creativity solving problems like the idea you got of considering those tricky vectors. I can follow math proofs prety well but still happens sometimes I lack of creativity to came with all these voila tricks or constructing counterexaples and examples so quickly.

Comment: @Cos I didn't comment on your proof that $V\cap V_{-1} = \{0\},$ but it is correct if $\operatorname{char}K \neq 2.$ If $\operatorname{char}K \neq 2$, $2v = 0\implies v = 0.$ If $\operatorname{char}K = 2,$ then $2 = 0$ so $2v = 0$ is true for any $v.$ As for the question of how to develop intuition and how to think of solutions like this, I believe there are questions on this site about that very topic. However, my recommendation is to just keep trying to prove things and keep working on problems and learning more. As you're exposed to more math, you'll pick up more strategies and tricks.